# XML to JSON conversation

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, xml

I've an XML come from asmx. But for one reason I want to extract it into javascript section.

It has xml format. But I need just json portion, Here is the raw code:

```
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
    ""[{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, MID WESTERN ZONE(FARIDPUR)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"20\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, SOUTH WESTERN ZONE (KHULNA)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"25\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, SOUTH EASTERN ZONE(CHITTAGONG)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"24\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, NORTH EASTERN ZONE(SYLHET)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"21\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, CENTRAL ZONE (DHAKA)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"18\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, NORTHERN ZONE(RANGPUR)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"23\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, EASTERN ZONE(COMILLA)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"19\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, SOUTHERN ZONE(BARISAL)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"26\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, NORTH WESTERN ZONE (RAJSHAHI)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"22\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, MID WESTERN ZONE(FARIDPUR)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"20\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, SOUTH WESTERN ZONE (KHULNA)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"25\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, SOUTH EASTERN ZONE(CHITTAGONG)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"24\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, NORTH EASTERN ZONE(SYLHET)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"21\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, CENTRAL ZONE (DHAKA)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"18\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, NORTHERN ZONE(RANGPUR)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"23\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, EASTERN ZONE(COMILLA)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"19\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, SOUTHERN ZONE(BARISAL)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"26\"},{\"OFFICE_NAME\":\"CE, NORTH WESTERN ZONE (RAJSHAHI)\",\"OFFICE_ID\":\"22\"}]""
</string>
```

So, i've to trim `<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">""`   and `"</string>`
Frpm this i just need to extract json. But how can i do this?
any function available?

Comment: you can use `replace` method with regular expression

Comment: You'd need to remove the backslashes within the string too.